# C Double type displays zeros after point

Tags: c

I have this weird problem. When I write a double type number, it gets stored in the

```c
double data;
```

variable. Then when I compile and run the code the number gets printed out as for example `3697.0000` when I have written `3697.47595`.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const int n = 12;
int stack[n], top = -1;

double Read()
{
    int x = 0;
    if(top < 0)
        printf("Empty stack!");
    else
    {
        x = stack[top];
        top--;
    }
    return x;
}

void Write(int x)
{
    if(top == n-1)
        printf("The stack is full");
    else
    {
        top++;
        stack[top] = x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double data;
    printf("Enter a double (0 for quit): ");
    scanf("%lf", &data);
    while(data > 0)
    {
        Write(data);
        printf("Enter a double (0 for quit): ");
        scanf("%lf", &data);
    }
    printf("---------------------------");
    printf("\nThe stack contains:\n");
    while(top >= 0 )
        printf("%lf ", Read());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have asked two questions in the last hour. Focus on learning to program instead of learning to ask SO.

Answer (score 4):

The value is truncated to `int` because the elements of the array `stack`, the argument of `Write`, and the variable `x` to temporarily store the value in `Read` are `int`. Use `double` for them to deal with `double` value.